# Making Row Entries Pair Horizontally in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So this question is similar to one I've asked before, but slightly different.

I'm looking at data for clients who are admitted to and discharged from a program. For each admit and discharge they have an assessment done and are scored on it and sometimes they are admitted and discharged multiple times during a time period.

I need to be able to pair each clients admit score with their following discharge date so I can look at all clients who improved a certain amount from admit to discharge for each of their admits and discharges.

This is an dummy sample of how my data results are formatted right now:
[image: Before]

And this is how I'd ideally like it formatted:
[image]

But I'd take any point in the right direction or similar formatting help that would allow me to be able to compare all of the instances of admit and discharge scores for all the clients.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of images try to post the full tables or at least some code that could be useful to test. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) can come handy, so anyone can reuse the code for testing and answering.

Comment: could you also give the table structure ? are there 3 tables - user, admit and discharge information ?

Comment: How does John (Jon) only have a discharge? Does this really happen in the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the result, you can apply both the UNPIVOT and the PIVOT functions.  The UNPIVOT will convert your multiple columns of `date` and `score` into rows, then you can pivot those rows back into columns.

Then unpivot syntax will be similar to this:

```
select person,
  casenumber,
  ScoreType+'_'+col col,
  value,
  rn
from
(
  select person,
    casenumber,
    convert(varchar(10), date, 101) date,
    cast(score as varchar(10)) score,
    scoreType,
    row_number() over(partition by casenumber, scoretype
                      order by case scoretype when 'Admit' then 1 end, date) rn            
  from yourtable
) d
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (date, score)
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d9c0/3). This gives a result:

```
| PERSON | CASENUMBER |             COL |      VALUE | RN |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|    Jon |       3412 |  Discharge_date | 01/03/2013 |  1 |
|    Jon |       3412 | Discharge_score |         12 |  1 |
|     Al |       3452 |      Admit_date | 05/16/2013 |  1 |
|     Al |       3452 |     Admit_score |         15 |  1 |
|     Al |       3452 |  Discharge_date | 08/01/2013 |  1 |
|     Al |       3452 | Discharge_score |         13 |  1 |
```

As you can see this query also creates the new columns to then pivot.  So the final code will be:

```
select person, casenumber,
  Admit_Date, Admit_Score, Discharge_Date, Discharge_Score
from
(
  select person,
    casenumber,
    ScoreType+'_'+col col,
    value,
    rn
  from
  (
    select person,
      casenumber,
      convert(varchar(10), date, 101) date,
      cast(score as varchar(10)) score,
      scoreType,
      row_number() over(partition by casenumber, scoretype
                        order by case scoretype when 'Admit' then 1 end, date) rn

    from yourtable
  ) d
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (date, score)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (Admit_Date, Admit_Score, Discharge_Date, Discharge_Score)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d9c0/2). This gives a result:

```
| PERSON | CASENUMBER | ADMIT_DATE | ADMIT_SCORE | DISCHARGE_DATE | DISCHARGE_SCORE |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Al |       3452 | 05/16/2013 |          15 |     08/01/2013 |              13 |
|  Cindy |       6578 | 01/02/2013 |          17 |     03/04/2013 |              14 |
|  Cindy |       6578 | 03/04/2013 |          14 |     03/18/2013 |              12 |
|    Jon |       3412 |     (null) |      (null) |     01/03/2013 |              12 |
|  Kevin |       9868 | 01/18/2013 |          19 |     03/02/2013 |              15 |
|  Kevin |       9868 | 03/02/2013 |          15 |         (null) |          (null) |
|   Pete |       4765 | 02/06/2013 |          15 |         (null) |          (null) |
|  Susan |       5421 | 04/06/2013 |          19 |     05/07/2013 |              15 |
```

Comment: SQL Fiddle is my new favorite toy.

Comment: Thanks!This works but when I run it on the whole data set it only returns one set for each client, if they have more than just one pair of admits and discharges in only returns the most recent 2.  So for example if a client admits, discharges and then admits again it will return their most recent admit paired with their discharge and not the first admit which goes with the discharge.  Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: I wonder if it might work to somehow change the name for a person who's had a 2nd admit and discharge? Making them Susan2 for the next pair?

Comment: @Ransom Please see my edit, I added a `row_number()` to keep the rows unique so you will return separate rows for each person.

Comment: Ok, one more question.  How would I go about making it so I could filter results that have a discharge date within a certain date range.  I converted the date varchars into date format using: "CONVERT(date, RIGHT(Discharge_Date,4)+LEFT(Discharge_Date,2)+SUBSTRING(Discharge_Date,4,2)) as Discharge_Date," in the first select statement, but when I try to use "WHERE Discharge_Date BETWEEN 2012-01-01 AND 2013-03-01" at the end of the document I get this error: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12/26/2012' to data type int." If I don't have that where statement it runs just fine.

Comment: @Ransom Do the date filter in the inner subquery before the UNPIVOT, just add your WHERE clause to that query.  If that doesn't work, then on your outer select statement convert the discharge date to a date and apply your filter.

Comment: Well the problem is that before the UNPIVOT the data is not horizontally lined up, so I could exclude all of the discharges that are not in that date range, but it would still show everyone who had any admit scores, just with there discharges now as NULL if they didn't fit into that range wouldn't it? I'm looking for a way to see just the scores of everyone who discharged within the date range. Is there any way to filter the final result after the PIVOT

Comment: @Ransom Yes you should be able to filter after the PIVOT, you will need to cast the discharge_date as a date or datetime in the where clause.

Comment: Tried that as "WHERE CAST(Discharge_Date AS DATE) BETWEEN 2012-01-01 AND 2013-03-01", but now it's giving the error "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int". Is it the convert statement I'm using in the initial select?  Sorry about pestering you with little things like this.

Comment: @Ransom You need single quotes around the dates in the between = `BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-03-01'`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
ad.person, ad.CaseNumber, ad.Date as AdmitScoreDate, ad.Score as AdmitScore,
dis.date as DischargeScoreDate, dis.Score as DischargeScore
From
yourTable ad, yourTable dis
```

WHERE
ad.person=dis.person
and 
ad.ScoreType='Admit'
and d
is.ScoreType='Discharge';

Comment: Explain WHY this works. You're giving the OP a fish. Instead, teach them HOW to fish.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting on this forum. This query is an example of self join query where one table is queried twice using different alias names for a table so it is same as joining two tables on common columns. Admit data comes from one alias table and Discharge data comes from another alias table joined on common person column or even better on casenumber column  to avoid same names for   different persons.

Answer (score 1):

If all the columns you mentioned are in the same table, you can join on same table

```
 SELECT t1.person,
  t1.caseNumber,
   t1.date adate,
  t1.score  ascore,
  t1.scoreType ascoreType,
  t2.date ddate,
  t2.score  dscore,
  t2.scoreType dscoretype
FROM patient t1
join patient t2
on t1.casenumber=t2.casenumber
and t1.scoreType!=t2.scoreType
and t1.scoreType='Admit'
```

But this will not show you record of people who have been admitted and not discharged yet. I don't know if you were also looking for that information.

SQL Fiddle [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a807b/1)

Hope this helps!